# Modify number of rows/colums in WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: tinymce, mezzanine

In [Mezzanine](http://mezzanine.jupo.org), using the [WYSIWYG Editor](http://www.tinymce.com/), I cannot seem to be able to modify the number of rows and columns -- the numbers are greyed out.  Somewhat, I am assuming I am being dense and that is possible but how?